# Search API Solr: filter by hash or site?

Tags: 8, search

I am trying to index a few sites using the same core on the same Solr instance. What I want to do is now add a View, and add a filter to do one of the following:

- Filter by hash
- Filter by site

I also want to expose it - the ultimate goal is to have a list of checkboxes that filters results in sites, like a federated search. I want to see content from all sites, or only sites A and B, or only just site C.

However it does not appear that either option is available in Views.

Is this something that has to be done with hook_views_data_alter and provide my own plugin? Or am I missing something about Solr search?